# Nginx and PHP-Fmp php rewrite issues

Tags: php, nginx, openshift

Any time I load the website it downloads any .php file that isn't index.php.

I am trying to install this app:
[Team Pass (github)](http://tinyurl.com/m527dde)

nginx Config:

```
# This nginx config file is preprocessed to replace all ${VARIABLES}
# with their values.

# Set another default user than root for security reasons
# user       www www;

# As a thumb rule: One per CPU. If you are serving a large amount
# of static files, which requires blocking disk reads, you may want
# to increase this from the number of cpu_cores available on your
# system.
#
# The maximum number of connections for Nginx is calculated by:
# max_clients = worker_processes * worker_connections
worker_processes 1;

# Maximum file descriptors that can be opened per process
# This should be > worker_connections
worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;

error_log ${OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR}/error.log;
pid ${OPENSHIFT_RUN_DIR}/nginx.pid;

events {
  # When you need > 8000 * cpu_cores connections, you start optimizing
  # your OS, and this is probably the point at where you hire people
  # who are smarter than you, this is *a lot* of requests.
  worker_connections  8000;

  # This sets up some smart queueing for accept(2)'ing requests
  # Set it to "on" if you have > worker_processes
  accept_mutex off;

  # These settings are OS specific, by defualt Nginx uses select(2),
  # however, for a large number of requests epoll(2) and kqueue(2)
  # are generally faster than the default (select(2))
  # use epoll; # enable for Linux 2.6+
  # use kqueue; # enable for *BSD (FreeBSD, OS X, ..)
}

http {
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    # Format for our log files
    log_format   main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  $status '
      '"$request" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 5;
    access_log ${OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR}/access.log;

    port_in_redirect off;
    server_tokens off;

    tcp_nopush on; # off may be better for Comet/long-poll stuff
    tcp_nodelay off; # on may be better for Comet/long-poll stuff

    # Enable Gzip
    gzip  on;
    gzip_http_version 1.0;
    gzip_comp_level 2;
    gzip_min_length 1100;
    gzip_buffers     4 8k;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types
      # text/html is always compressed by HttpGzipModule
      text/css
      text/javascript
      text/xml
      text/plain
      text/x-component
      application/javascript
      application/json
      application/xml
      application/rss+xml
      font/truetype
      font/opentype
      application/vnd.ms-fontobject
      image/svg+xml;

    gzip_static on;

    gzip_proxied        expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_disable        "MSIE [1-6]\.";
    gzip_vary           on;

    server {
        # This will listen on all interfaces, you can instead choose a specific IP
        # such as listen x.x.x.x:80;  Setting listen 80 default_server; will make
        # this server block the default one if no other blocks match the request
        listen ${OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP}:${OPENSHIFT_DIY_PORT};

        # Here you can set a server name, you can use wildcards such as *.example.com
        # however remember if you use server_name *.example.com; You'll only match subdomains
        # to match both subdomains and the main domain use both example.com and *.example.com
        server_name  localhost;

        # It is best to place the root of the server block at the server level, and not the location level
        # any location block path will be relative to this root.
        root   ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}/web;

        # Forces modern clients to use secure connections only for at
        # least 8 days after the header was last returned. See:
        # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=691200;

        location / {
            index  index.html  index.htm  index.php ;

            try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrites;
        }

        location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

        location ~ /\.          { access_log off; log_not_found off; deny all; }
        location ~ ~$           { access_log off; log_not_found off; deny all; }

        # Set expires max on static file types
        location ~* ^.+\.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|gz|svg|svgz|ttf|otf|woff|eot|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm)$ {
            access_log off;
            log_not_found off;

            # Some basic cache-control for static files to be sent to the browser
            expires max;
            add_header Pragma public;
            add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
        }

        location @rewrites {
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
            fastcgi_pass unix:${OPENSHIFT_RUN_DIR}/php-fpm.socket;

            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;

            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    # opt-in to the future
    add_header "X-UA-Compatible" "IE=Edge,chrome=1";
}
```

Things tried:

[Default type change](http://tinyurl.com/kw7cbz8)

As this worked to load the html obviously left the rest nonfunctional.

Next.

```
    location @rewrites {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
}
```

to

```
location @rewrites {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?_url=/$1;
}
```

Caused error on loading the config

Lastly tried putting index.php in front under `location / {`
That also caused an error on loading the config.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {`
should be
`location ~ \.php(/|$) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like @maxivanov commented, you explicitly told `nginx` to only pass `index.php` to the `php` socket

```
location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
```

So what is happening to you is the expected behaviour, if you want to process the remaining files make the `php` block more generic

```
location ~ \.php$ {
```

reload `nginx` then every thing would work